# how to parse a uniprot-file with parsec?

Tags: haskell

I am a newbie to Haskell, but it seems like a powerful language that I want to learn. I was adopting some code from the chapter in real world Haskell on parsec. I tried to make my own version of it parsing the content of a uniprot-file. This is a file that consists of records (that starts with ">"), and where each record consists of lines. My code seems very close to what is done in the example, but I am getting a lot of errors - mostly on types. My exception is among other that I am taking the output of readFile (IO string) instead of a string. I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand what is wrong in my approach...

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

main:: IO()

parseSprot :: IO String -> Either ParseError [[String]]

parseSprot input = parse uniprotFile "(unknown)" input
    where   
        uniprotFile = endBy record eol
        record = sepBy lines (char '>')
        lines = many (noneOf ",\n")
        eol = char '\n'

main = do 
    parseSprot $ readFile "uniprot_sprot.fasta" 
    putStrLn "hey"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseSprot` doesn't need an `IO` in its signature.

```
parseSprot :: String -> Either ParseError [[String]]
...
```

The result of `readFile` is an `IO String`. You can do something with this `String` by binding the result of the `readFile` action into a new `IO` action. In `do` notation you can bind the result to a variable with `<-`

```
main = do 
    fileContents <- readFile "uniprot_sprot.fasta"
```

The `parseSprot` function doesn't return a result in `IO`, you can use it anywhere. In `do` notation we tell the difference between a result bound to a variable and a declaration by using different syntax. `x <- ...` binds a result to a variable. `let x = ...` declares `x` to be whatever is on the right hand side.

```
main = do 
    fileContents <- readFile "uniprot_sprot.fasta" 
    let parsedContents = parseSprot fileContents
```

To test what your parser is doing, you might want to `print` the value returned from `parse`.

```
main = do 
    fileContents <- readFile "uniprot_sprot.fasta" 
    let parsedContents = parseSprot fileContents
    print parsedContents
```

Without `do` notation you can write this as

```
main = readFile "uniprot_sprot.fasta" >>= print . parseSprot
```

`>>=` takes the result of the first computation and feeds it into a function to decide what to do next.

Comment: this was really great help, sorry to bother you again, but I thought this would result in a list of records (a larger string chunk starting with ´>´ and ending before the next ´>´. How would I keep the records intact instead of defining them as a list of lines?

Comment: @hotGopher Perhaps you should post another question for that? If you do, you should include an example input and what the desired result of parsing that input is.