# How to parse into records?

Tags: haskell

I have a asked a question before, which I learned from. I discovered that the implementation resulted in a list of strings rather than a list of records. The file I am parsing has records that looks like;

> sp|P30375|1A01_GORGO Class I histocompatibility antigen Gogo-A*0101 alpha chain OS=Gorilla gorilla gorilla PE=2 SV=1
>   MAVMAPRTLVLLLSGALALTQTWAGSHSMRYFSTSVSRPGRGEPRFIAVGYVDDTQFVRF
>   DSDAASQRMEPRAPWIEQEGPEYWDRNTRNVKAHSQTDRVDLGTLRGYYNQSEDGSHTIQ
>   RMYGCDVGSDGRFLRGYQQDAYDGKDYIALNEDLRSWTAADMAAEITKRKWEAAHFAEQL
>   RAYLEGTCVEWLRRHLENGKETLQRTDAPKTHMTHHAVSDHEAILRCWALSFYPAEITLT
>   WQRDGEDQTQDTELVETRPAGDGTFQKWAAVVVPSGQEQRYTCHVQHEGLPEPLTLRWEP
>   SSQPTIPIVGIIAGLVLFGAVIAGAVVAAVRWRRKSSDRKGGSYSQAASSDSAQGSDVSL
>   TACKV
>   sp|P30443|1A01_HUMAN HLA class I histocompatibility antigen A-1 alpha chain OS=Homo sapiens GN=HLA-A PE=1 SV=1
>   MAVMAPRTLLLLLSGALALTQTWAGSHSMRYFFTSVSRPGRGEPRFIAVGYVDDTQFVRF
>   DSDAASQKMEPRAPWIEQEGPEYWDQETRNMKAHSQTDRANLGTLRGYYNQSEDGSHTIQ
>   IMYGCDVGPDGRFLRGYRQDAYDGKDYIALNEDLRSWTAADMAAQITKRKWEAVHAAEQR
>   RVYLEGRCVDGLRRYLENGKETLQRTDPPKTHMTHHPISDHEATLRCWALGFYPAEITLT
>   WQRDGEDQTQDTELVETRPAGDGTFQKWAAVVVPSGEEQRYTCHVQHEGLPKPLTLRWEL
>   SSQPTIPIVGIIAGLVLLGAVITGAVVAAVMWRRKSSDRKGGSYTQAASSDSAQGSDVSL
>   TACKV

just before the sp there is a ">", which I planned to use as a records divide point. So, how can I end up with:

```
[[>sp|P30375|1A01_GORGO Class I histocompatibility antigen Gogo-A*0101 alpha chain OS=Gorilla gorilla gorilla PE=2 SV=1
MAVMAPRTLVLLLSGALALTQTWAGSHSMRYFSTSVSRPGRGEPRFIAVGYVDDTQFVRF
DSDAASQRMEPRAPWIEQEGPEYWDRNTRNVKAHSQTDRVDLGTLRGYYNQSEDGSHTIQ
RMYGCDVGSDGRFLRGYQQDAYDGKDYIALNEDLRSWTAADMAAEITKRKWEAAHFAEQL
RAYLEGTCVEWLRRHLENGKETLQRTDAPKTHMTHHAVSDHEAILRCWALSFYPAEITLT
WQRDGEDQTQDTELVETRPAGDGTFQKWAAVVVPSGQEQRYTCHVQHEGLPEPLTLRWEP
SSQPTIPIVGIIAGLVLFGAVIAGAVVAAVRWRRKSSDRKGGSYSQAASSDSAQGSDVSL
TACKV]
[>sp|P30443|1A01_HUMAN HLA class I histocompatibility antigen A-1 alpha chain OS=Homo sapiens GN=HLA-A PE=1 SV=1
MAVMAPRTLLLLLSGALALTQTWAGSHSMRYFFTSVSRPGRGEPRFIAVGYVDDTQFVRF
DSDAASQKMEPRAPWIEQEGPEYWDQETRNMKAHSQTDRANLGTLRGYYNQSEDGSHTIQ
IMYGCDVGPDGRFLRGYRQDAYDGKDYIALNEDLRSWTAADMAAQITKRKWEAVHAAEQR
RVYLEGRCVDGLRRYLENGKETLQRTDPPKTHMTHHPISDHEATLRCWALGFYPAEITLT
WQRDGEDQTQDTELVETRPAGDGTFQKWAAVVVPSGEEQRYTCHVQHEGLPKPLTLRWEL
SSQPTIPIVGIIAGLVLLGAVITGAVVAAVMWRRKSSDRKGGSYTQAASSDSAQGSDVSL
TACKV]]
```

using parsec? This is the code I started out with; [how to parse a uniprot-file with parsec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380363/how-to-parse-a-uniprot-file-with-parsec)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem you only need to parse records separated by '>'. Then you records is a string containing all characters but '>' and you are looking for something like this:

```
import Control.Applicative ((*>))
import Text.Parsec 
import Text.Parsec.ByteString  (Parser,parseFromFile)

type Record = String 

parserFile :: FilePath -> IO [Record]
parserFile fileName = do 
     r <- parseFromFile parseRecords fileName 
     case r of
        Left  msg  -> error . show $ msg
        Right xs -> return xs


parseRecords :: Parser [Record]
parseRecords = many1 $ (char '>')  *> (many1 $ noneOf ['>'])
```

The "parseFromFile" function read the data using the efficient binary representation and takes as another argument a parser to analyze the stream of bytestrings resulting from reading the file.

Now, all you records begin with the '>' symbol, therefore you only need a parser that match the '>' symbol at the beggining and store the rest of the symbols in a list until the next '>' symbol.

Comment: and how can I print my records? I thought that: let records = parserFile "uniprot_sprot.fasta", let fstrecord = head records, would give me a list of records ([Record]) and that fstrecord would now be the first record of that list.

Comment: ParserFile is a monadic computation (IO [Records]), therefore if you want to operate with the content of your records, you should do it inside the monadic context, for instance in the case statement, like: "Right xs -> print $ head xs". But Now the type is IO () and also you must change the Left statement to: Left msg -> print msg